# Setting up a Kubernetes master on a different IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm trying to set up a Kubernetes master on an IP other than the one assigned to the default interface. These are the changes I made to my `kubeadm-config.yml` :

```yaml
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
controlPlaneEndpoint: x.x.x.x
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    advertise-address: x.x.x.x
  certSANs:
    - x.x.x.x
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
    extraArgs:
      advertise-client-urls: https://x.x.x.x:2379
      initial-advertise-peer-urls: https://x.x.x.x:2380
      initial-cluster: my-hostname=https://x.x.x.x:2380
      listen-client-urls: https://127.0.0.1:2379,https://x.x.x.x:2379
      listen-peer-urls: https://x.x.x.x:2380
      initial-cluster-state: new
    serverCertSANs:
      - x.x.x.x
    peerCertSANs:
      - x.x.x.x
```

Where `x.x.x.x` is the non-default IP.
Everything seems to be set correctly, except for the liveness probe of the api-server. At `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` I still see

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 8
  httpGet:
    host: y.y.y.y
    path: /healthz
    port: 6443
    scheme: HTTPS
```

Where `y.y.y.y` is the old IP.

Does anyone know what key I need to add to my `kubeadm-config.yml` to set this right?

Sam

Comment: Does creating new cluster with specific IP is an option or you want to change current IP address on existing cluster?

Comment: Creating a cluster (more specifically a single node cluster) with a specific IP is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Could you tell more about this second IP? Is that another machine? Its your local environment? Are you using some cloud features? Did this second IP is reserved IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproducing your configuration, I found out that the `InitConfiguration` part of `kubeadm-config` is required for that.

The following `kubeadm-config.yaml` part is supposed to instruct `kubeadm` to configure `kube-apiserver` according to your needs:

```
---
kind: InitConfiguration
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: "x.x.x.x"
  bindPort: 6443

# the next section is optional, but could be useful also
nodeRegistration:
  kubeletExtraArgs:
    cgroup-driver: "systemd"
```

For the full details please read related GoDoc page:

- [k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta2](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/apis/kubeadm/v1beta2)

Comment: Thanks. Adding that `InitConfiguration` object was in fact the only thing I had to add. I could leave my `ClusterConfiguration` as is.